# How do I make a spider farm in my kitchen to eat flies in the house?

Tags: kitchens, pest-control

I am planning on making an area set aside in the kitchen to breed and grow spiders to kill flies in the kitchen. This is completely theoretical right now, just something I am pondering, so I don't really have all the details fleshed out. What I am planning to do is to make this triangular box so that it will fit in the corner of the kitchen. Then, I will coat the bottom of the box with whatever flies are attracted to (I think it was vinegar?). Finally, I'll need to get some spiders, I probably have a couple of them crawling around the house. However, I am not sure what to use as the lid of the spider farm so that no spiders or baby spiders will escape while also letting flies and vinegar get in. Any ideas? Also, do you think my spider farm idea is effective for getting rid of flies or as stupid as it sounds?

Comment: Get some Venus fly traps :)

Comment: This seems like an animal-husbandry and insect/arachnid behavior question, not a Home Improvement question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about home improvement.

Comment: Politely, this is not an improvement to a home.  Finding and remediating the source of what attracts the flies would be a better solution.   Consider relocating sources of smell, like trash cans.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an entomologist, but...this isn't going to work. My non-expert intuition here is that spiders don't want to live in a box, and they especially don't want to live with other spiders in a box. Also, if you're going to the trouble of luring flies into a box, maybe just put some fly paper in there? Sometimes simpler is better.

P.S. The expression is "you catch more flies with honey than with vinegar," but actual non-metaphorical flies seem pretty crazy about dog poop, so I don't think they're too fussy.

P.P.S. Please don't put dog poop in your spider farm.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is fine.   But you can't chicken out.   As long as you get enough spiders and let them cover a good deal of your kitchen in webs, the flies will be gone in no time.  You really have to go all in on this and not sure how sanitary that is for a kitchen.   But you have to continue having a small fly problem or the spiders could turn on each other.

Or you can just keep your doors closed and be careful about the produce you bring in the home and how you store it.    I don't get the "fly problem" unless you live really close to others and they are causing the issue.   You should figure out why flies are getting into your home and stop doing those things if you want it to stop.   Yes I have had flies in many houses.   And no there was never a house that stumped me on why flies where a problem.   This is not like other bugs that are sneaky.   Flies a very robotic and are produced and travel in very "programable" patterns.